# Change index assign from liquid with javascript

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

i want to assgin index in liquid and i want to use javascript to change this index in liquid.
I try to find this for a long time. So can anyone help me. 
this is my code example 
in liquid file: `{% assign index = 0 %}` and show it `{{ index }}` 
in javascript i use splide to change when slide :

```js
import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const splide =  new Splide('.splide', {
    type   : 'loop',
    perPage: 4,
    perMove: 1,
  } ).mount();
  splide.on( 'move', function () {
  console.log(splide.index)

  } );
});
```

Comment: Liquid is compiled before the execution of any javascript. This mean that you can't modify any liquid from javascript. So what you are describing is not possible.

Comment: okay thanks about that.I will find another way